# executing JS function and define variable from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I have is a page which is gathering a large list of data via jQuery. I am trying to limit the amount of results shown to a variable, and change the results shown on the list to create a false-page effect. Everything works via the same JS function, and relies on 1 variable to make everything work. Simple. I've removed all of the extra code to simplify everything

```
function myFunction() { var page = 1; console.log(page); }
```

I am looking for a way to call on this function, but change the variable 'page' from within html. Something along the lines of:

```
<a href="" onclick="myFunction(page=2)"> 2 </a>
```

I have been looking on google (and still am) I just can't seem to find what I am looking for. I'm trying to avoid multiple pages/refreshing as this element is going to be used for a larger project on the same page.

**UPDATE:** I managed to pass the intended values through to a JS function like so...

```
function myFunction(page) { console.log(page); }
```

...and...

```
<input type='button' onclick='myFunction(value)' value='input page number'>
```

This seems the simplest way of doing what I need, what do you think?
Thanks for your help btw guys.

Comment: One option is to add the desired variable value a custom attribute to your anchor tag and just access it in the javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can add the data-url attribute to your markup and select on the `.link` class to fetch the `data-url` attribute for each element thats part of that class.

> I'm trying to avoid multiple pages/refreshing as this element is going
>   to be used for a larger project on the same page.

Sounds like you also want an AJAX solution.

```js
$(document).ready( function()
{
  //Add this on your call.html page
    $(".link").click(function()
    {                
        //location of test JSON file
        var root = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com';
        
        //your custom attribute acting as your 'variable'
        var page = $(this).attr('data-url');
        console.log("page = " + page);
        
        //remove any previous html from the modal
        $(".modal-content").empty();
        
        //send a request to the server to retrieve your pages
        $.ajax(
        {
          method: "GET",
          //this should be updated with location of file
          url: root + '/posts/' + page,
          //if server request to get page was successful
          success: function(result)
          {          
            console.log(result);
            var res = result;            
            var content = "<div class='panel-default'><div class='panel-heading'><h3 class='panel-title'>" + res.title + "</h3></div><i><div class='panel-body'>''" + res.body + "''</i></div><p><u> Master Yoda, (2017)</u></p><p class='page'> Page: " + page + "</p></div>";
            
            $(".modal-content").html(content);
          },
          //otherwise do this
          error: function(result)
          {
            $(".modal-content").html("<div class='error'><span><b> Failed to retrieve data </b></span><p> try again later </p></div>");
          }
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.error
{
  border: 2px dotted red;
  margin: 5px;
}

a
{
  font-size: 20px;
}

.page
{
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a class="link" data-url="1" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" href="test.html">Show Page 1</a>
<br />
<a class="link" data-url="2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal" href="">Show Page 2</a>

<div id="Modal" class="modal fade text-center">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this you will need to move the page variable to be a parameter of myFunction

```
function myFunction(page) { console.log(page); }
```

Then you can just pass in whatever page number you would like

```
<a href="" onclick="myFunction(2)"> 2 </a>
```

Comment: This would be the simplest solution, and I think this is what 'mrogers' was saying. The problem is that there are other calculations based off the variable so it needs to stay defined in this way.Also there is a refresh function to keep the data displayed on the list current and doing it this way seems to make the list disappear, but I might be able to fix that. I have a few things to try out now so thanks for your answers so far I will post back shortly.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have figured out how to do this. I wanted to stray from using lots of libraries in the project and just wanted to keep things simple, using the above answers for guidance (and a little more digging), basically my end goal was to use jQuery to obtain a long list of data, and format this data into a multiple page list (for which I used a table for formatting purposes). Let's say it's a list of names. The JSON results output as:

```
[{"first_name":"Bob"},{"last_name":"Jones"}]     // (key, value)
```

But when I passed this through to the HTML Table it was just displaying 1000s of results in a single list, and formatting the list was a pain. This was my solution:

```
<script>
var pageNum = "";     // define Page Number variable for later.
var resLimit = 35;    // variable to specify the number of results per page
function updateList () {
    $.getJSON(" Location of JSON results ", function(data) {
        var pageCount = Math.round(data.length/resLimit);    // calculate number of pages
        var auto_id = ((pageNum-1)*resLimit)    // use variables to give each result an id
        var newListData = "";    // define this for use later
```

then define and pass "new list data" to HTML Table:

```
var newListData = "";
    $.each(data.slice(auto_id, (pageNum*resLimit)), function(key, value) {
        auto_id++;
        newListData += '<tr>';
        newListData += '<td class="id">' + audo_id + '</td>';
        newListData += '<td class="id">' + value.first_name + '</td>';
        newListData += '<td class="id">' + value.last_name + '</td>';
        newListData += '</tr>';
    });
    $('# ID of table, data will replace existing rows ').html(newListData);
```

At this point if you set the value of pageNum to 1 you should see the first 35 results on the list, all with auto-incremented ID numbers. If you change it to 2 and refresh the page you should see the next 35, with the ID numbers following on from the first page.

Next I needed to create a button for each of the pages:

```
$('# ID of table, data will replace existing rows ').html(newListData);
function createButtons() {
    var buttonArray = "";
    for(i=0, x=pageCount; i<x; i++) {
        buttonArray += '<input type="button" onclick="changePage(' 
            + (i + 1) + ')" value="' + (i + 1) + '">';
        }
    $('#  ID of Span tags for button container  ').html(buttonArray);   }
createButtons();
});    }
</script>
```

Then create changePage() and a function to refresh the data in the list automatically without messing things up

```
<script>
var pageNum = "";
function changePage(page) {
    if (pageNum < 1) { pageNum = 1; } // set pageNum when the page loads
    if (page > 0) { pageNum = page; } // overwrite pageNum when 'page' variable is defined
    updateList();    }
changePage();    // initialise to prevent delayed display on page load

// refresh function:
function refreshData() {
    changePage(0); //  define 'page' as 0 so that pageNum is not overwritten
    window.setTimeout(refreshData, 5000);    } // loop this function every 5 seconds to
refreshData();                            //-- keep this list populated with current data.
```

And that should just about do it! At least it's working for me but I might have missed something (hopefully not lol). Hope this helps someone theres quite a few things involved in this that could be extrapolated and used elsewhere :)

thanks for help everyone.